# Access 2003 SQL Syntax error in join message

Tags: sql

I am new at coding in SQL for access 2003 and I am having a problem showing a additional column called Action which is shown on the tLEDGERS table. I am recieving a syntax error message but I am not sure why?

**Below is the code snippet causing the issue**

FROM (tDailyEntries
INNER JOIN tDailyEntries
ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo)

**Below is the full code**

```
SELECT DISTINCT tProjects.CC_IO AS ProjectNo,
Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")" AS [Line/Item/Text],
tUsers.LastName AS Last_Name, 
tDailyEntries.UserId AS UserID, 
contractordailyrate AS DailyRate, 
contractordailyhours AS Hours, 
ROUND(contractordailyrate / contractordailyhours, 2) AS HourlyRate,
ROUND(SUM(tDailyEntries.CalculatedDailyHours), 2) AS MonthlyHours, 
ROUND((HourlyRate * MonthlyHours), 2) AS Charge, 
ROUND(Charge+ROUND((Charge*0.2),2),2) AS Accruals, tProjects.Project AS Project
FROM (tDailyEntries
INNER JOIN tDailyEntries
ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo)
FROM (tProjectType 
RIGHT JOIN tProjects ON tProjectType.ProjectTypeID = tProjects.ProjectTypeID) 
RIGHT JOIN (textcontractor 
RIGHT JOIN (tTitle 
RIGHT JOIN (((tLocation 
RIGHT JOIN (tDepartments 
RIGHT JOIN tUsers 
ON tDepartments.DeptID = tUsers.DeptID) 
ON tLocation.LocationID = tUsers.LocationID) 
RIGHT JOIN (((tDailyEntries 
LEFT JOIN tDepartments AS tDepartments_1 
ON tDailyEntries.DeptCharged = tDepartments_1.DeptShortName) 
LEFT JOIN tActions ON tDailyEntries.ActionNo = tActions.ActionID) 
LEFT JOIN tLookups 
ON tDailyEntries.Zone = tLookups.LookupID) 
ON tUsers.UserID = tDailyEntries.UserID) 
LEFT JOIN textmain 
ON tUsers.UserID = textmain.userID) 
ON tTitle.TitleID = tUsers.TitleID) 
ON textcontractor.companyid = textmain.contractorcompany) 
ON tProjects.ProjectID = tDailyEntries.ProjectNo
WHERE tTitle.TitleID = 37 
AND Month([DateFrom]) = MonthNum 
AND Day([DateFrom]) <21
GROUP BY tProjects.CC_IO, Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")", tUsers.LastName, tDailyEntries.UserId, textmain.contractordailyrate, 
Month([DateFrom]), textmain.contractordailyhours, tProjects.Project;
```

Please see my updated code below

```
SELECT DISTINCT tProjects.CC_IO AS ProjectNo,
Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")" AS [Line/Item/Text],
tUsers.LastName AS Last_Name, 
tDailyEntries.UserId AS UserID, 
contractordailyrate AS DailyRate, 
contractordailyhours AS Hours, 
ROUND(contractordailyrate / contractordailyhours, 2) AS HourlyRate,
ROUND(SUM(tDailyEntries.CalculatedDailyHours), 2) AS MonthlyHours, 
ROUND((HourlyRate * MonthlyHours), 2) AS Charge, 
ROUND(Charge+ROUND((Charge*0.2),2),2) AS Accruals, tProjects.Project AS Project
FROM (tDailyEntries INNER JOIN tLEDGERS 
ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo)
FROM (tProjectType 
RIGHT JOIN tProjects ON tProjectType.ProjectTypeID = tProjects.ProjectTypeID) 
RIGHT JOIN (textcontractor 
RIGHT JOIN (tTitle 
RIGHT JOIN (((tLocation 
RIGHT JOIN (tDepartments 
RIGHT JOIN tUsers 
ON tDepartments.DeptID = tUsers.DeptID) 
ON tLocation.LocationID = tUsers.LocationID) 
RIGHT JOIN (((tDailyEntries 
LEFT JOIN tDepartments AS tDepartments_1 
ON tDailyEntries.DeptCharged = tDepartments_1.DeptShortName) 
LEFT JOIN tActions ON tDailyEntries.ActionNo = tActions.ActionID) 
LEFT JOIN tLookups 
ON tDailyEntries.Zone = tLookups.LookupID) 
ON tUsers.UserID = tDailyEntries.UserID) 
LEFT JOIN textmain 
ON tUsers.UserID = textmain.userID) 
ON tTitle.TitleID = tUsers.TitleID) 
ON textcontractor.companyid = textmain.contractorcompany) 
ON tProjects.ProjectID = tDailyEntries.ProjectNo
WHERE tTitle.TitleID = 37 
AND Month([DateFrom]) = MonthNum 
AND Day([DateFrom]) <21
GROUP BY tProjects.CC_IO, Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")", tUsers.LastName, tDailyEntries.UserId, textmain.contractordailyrate, 
Month([DateFrom]), textmain.contractordailyhours, tProjects.Project;
```

updated code 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT tProjects.CC_IO AS ProjectNo,
Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")" AS [Line/Item/Text],
tUsers.LastName AS Last_Name, 
tDailyEntries.UserId AS UserID, 
contractordailyrate AS DailyRate, 
contractordailyhours AS Hours, 
ROUND(contractordailyrate / contractordailyhours, 2) AS HourlyRate,
ROUND(SUM(tDailyEntries.CalculatedDailyHours), 2) AS MonthlyHours, 
ROUND((HourlyRate * MonthlyHours), 2) AS Charge, 
ROUND(Charge+ROUND((Charge*0.2),2),2) AS Accruals, tProjects.Project AS Project
FROM (tDailyEntries
INNER JOIN tLEDGERS ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo)
INNER JOIN (tProjects ON tProjectType.ProjectTypeID = tProjects.ProjectTypeID
RIGHT JOIN (textcontractor 
RIGHT JOIN (tTitle 
RIGHT JOIN (((tLocation 
RIGHT JOIN (tDepartments 
RIGHT JOIN tUsers 
ON tDepartments.DeptID = tUsers.DeptID) 
ON tLocation.LocationID = tUsers.LocationID) 
RIGHT JOIN (((tDailyEntries 
LEFT JOIN tDepartments AS tDepartments_1 
ON tDailyEntries.DeptCharged = tDepartments_1.DeptShortName) 
LEFT JOIN tActions ON tDailyEntries.ActionNo = tActions.ActionID) 
LEFT JOIN tLookups 
ON tDailyEntries.Zone = tLookups.LookupID) 
ON tUsers.UserID = tDailyEntries.UserID) 
LEFT JOIN textmain 
ON tUsers.UserID = textmain.userID) 
ON tTitle.TitleID = tUsers.TitleID) 
ON textcontractor.companyid = textmain.contractorcompany) 
ON tProjects.ProjectID = tDailyEntries.ProjectNo
WHERE tTitle.TitleID = 37 
AND Month([DateFrom]) = MonthNum 
AND Day([DateFrom]) <21
GROUP BY tProjects.CC_IO, Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")", tUsers.LastName, tDailyEntries.UserId, textmain.contractordailyrate, 
Month([DateFrom]), textmain.contractordailyhours, tProjects.Project;
```

Answer (score 0):

That `JOIN` operation is wrong cause it depicts that you are doing a `self join` on `tDailyEntries` but join `ON` condition contradicts that since you are trying to match with `tLEDGERS.Action`. I believe you meant to do

```
.....
FROM tDailyEntries INNER JOIN tLEDGERS 
ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo
```

Per Comment:

You have two `FROM` clause in your query as below

```
FROM (tDailyEntries
INNER JOIN tDailyEntries
ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo)
FROM (tProjectType
```

Change that to

```
FROM tDailyEntries
INNER JOIN tLEDGERS
ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo
INNER JOIN tProjectType ON ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I inserted the join operation into the code and am now getting syntax error in FROM clause. Am I allowed to FROM statements in this query? below is my amended code

Comment: @userD, check answer again. Do a sanity/syntax checking of your query before executing.

Comment: I am still hitting syntax errors with this new join operation. I have added the code into update 2 above for you

Comment: @userD, No offense but I don't like spoon feeding. My answer gives you enough pointer to start with; just follow along the line and fix rest of the similar syntax error you have in your query.

Comment: Thanks anyway Rahul. The syntax error on the join operation still remanins. Does anyone else know what is wronf with my code I have accounted for all brackets and operators and still not working